# Angular 2 display page based on user authentication without changing route

Tags: url, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I've been searching for this solution for 2 hours and couldn't find relevant topic so i'm going to ask it myself.

I have this angular 2 app, in which there is an authentication, i want the logic to be like facebook or any other site that has authentication, when user logs in to my

> localhost

i want to display the login page, after user logs in i want the url to stay the same but display different page from my angular components,

is there any way without `if(condition)` inside template to do that?

Right now my app does this like this:

> Localhost -> loging -> Localhost/example-logged-in-page

Comment: Why do you not want to use the template conditions ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in having a different URL when logging in and once user's logged. Nothing wrong with using `*ngIf` too if you really want to go this way